# How the UI get updated in Redux Todolist example

Tags: reactjs, redux

All:

I am pretty new to React and Redux, when I read the [TodoList](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html) example code(although it is the simple to ReactJSers, but still very complicated to me ), I wonder after we dispatch the action, and the store change the todo, where does the UI get noticed to update its view? I thought there should be some code like `setState()`, but I can not find it.

So, could anyone give me a hint how the subscribe works in this example, you can start from:

**VisibleTodoList.js**

```
onTodoClick: (id) => {
  dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
}
```

Or

U can talk with this [Counter example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter), after onClick(either onIncrement or onDecrement ) triggered, how does React know store.getState() should be called and the component inside Counter should be updated?

```
<Counter
      value={store.getState()}
      onIncrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })}
      onDecrement={() => store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })}
    />,
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notice last line in https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter/index.js
There is attached listener:

```
store.subscribe(render)
```

According to the Redux documentation:

> Adds a change listener. It will be called any time an action is dispatched, and some part of the state tree may potentially have changed. You may then call getState() to read the current state tree inside the callback.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it how counter works, could you u help with how that todolist example achieve this?

Comment: The listener is called every time you dispatch new action which triggers reducer https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/counter/reducers/index.js which does copying of the state and modifies proper property of the copied state.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I did not quite catch u with this part,  I think my question is more about after the reducer runs, how the component knows it and update the UI in **TodoList** example? My understanding is the reducer only deals with the store data, but it does not tell those "container" components that the store data changed. From the Reactjs perspective, the component only update UI when the props given new value, which in our case should be the container component pass data from store to presentational component, but how the container component knows data change in state?

Comment: In this particular example the component doesn't know anything. It is called because it is wrapped with a function render, which function later is attached to listener, which listener is called with every dispatch.

Comment: Thanks, so the props assignment is done in that function render?

Comment: Indeed in line: value={store.getState()}, and this value is received either here: this.props.value % 2 !== 0) or here: Clicked: {value} times